# rmdir throwing error but still working

Tags: php, server, directory, rmdir

I have two lines of code:

```
$path = $_GET['path'];
rmdir(realpath($path));
```

What they do should be pretty obvious.
Anyway, each time it is run, the text "Path is not a directory" is displayed in the browser - but checking the filesystem shows that the directory has actually been removed.

I am using WAMP on Windows.

I am guessing its something related to the formatting of the path. Currently, a path looks like C:\ilmiont_server\blog.

Any advice appreciated,
Ilmiont

Comment: Yes, have you tried `rmdir($path);` ? Besides, you should definitely do some checking before deleting a path provided in a `$_GET` variable

Comment: So did I initially.. but it makes no difference. "Path is not a directory" either way.. but somehow the directory gets deleted every time, with or without realpath() call.

Comment: Ah I see. In your example, $_GET["path"] = "C:\ilmiont_server\blog".

Comment: Yes, that would be correct.

Comment: And you don't want to specify paths relatively to your server root ? That would be easier :) As far as I could read, `realpath()` does the opposite of what you need

Comment: Hmm you may be right. I'll reconsider some things. This is part of a CMS I am developing - "delete directory" in the server file browser, for background.

Answer (score 0):

Try add a final slash to the path.. or something like:

```
rmdir( realpath($path) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );
```